# Move a div to top : absolute position to specific div

Tags: jquery, css

This is my websites layout on desktop and mobile.

[image]

I want to show the search form at the top of the page once someone clicks on the blue colour `link`. Because the search form is at the bottom of the page Im finding it hard to `position` `absolute` and get it to top. Is it possible to make it absolutely position to the wrapper `div` based on its `id` or can I make it popup at the top using some jquery. Please help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this....

```
<div class="link">
   <div class="search"></div>
</div>
```

CSS code

```
.link{position:relative;}
.search{position:absolute; top:0px;}
```

If you want to it bottom

```
.search{position:absolute; bottom:0px;}
```